# affine spaces, affine hyperplanes

Tags: vector-spaces

I am totally confused with the definition of affine spaces and affine hyperplanes.  Informally an affine subspace is a space obtained from a vector space by forgetting about the origin. Mathematically an affine space is a set A together with a vector space V with a transitive free action of V on A. We will call V the group of translations of A. Affine subspace U of V is nothing but a constant vector added to a linear subspace. That is U is of the form W+b with W a subspace of V. Then here what is the translation group?

Now let $V$ be a vector space with a symmetric bilinear form $(,)$. Then for $0\neq \alpha \in V$ the set $H_\alpha=\{  \lambda \in V:( \lambda,\alpha)=0\}$ is a hyperplane. Consider the translation of $H_\alpha$,

$H_{\alpha,1}= \{  \lambda \in V:( \lambda,\alpha)=1\}$. Then how $H_{\alpha,1}$ is an affine hyperplane? What is its translation group? 
Please help me.

Comment: What do you mean, "Then here what is the translation group?"? Do you mean, what is the group of translations preserving a given affine subspace?

Comment: An affine space is a set A to which is associated a vector space V over a field K and a transitive and free action of the additive group of V. The elements of the affine space A are called points, and the elements of the associated vector space V are called vectors, translations or, sometimes free vectors. This is the definition in the Wikipedia..

Comment: It's still not clear to me what you mean. If you mean the group of translations of $A$, then you said yourself that the group is $V$ (where the operation is vector space addition).

Comment: My doubt is how U=W+b an affine subspace. According to the abstract definition of an affine space ,it is a set together with a vector space acting on it freely and transitively. So here for U what is the corresponding vector space?

Comment: Okay, I see, then yes: The corresponding vector space (space of translations) is $W$ itself, as $U = W + b$ means that adding an element of $W$ to an element of $U$ gives and element of $U$, and $W$ is exactly the group of translations preserving $U$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $V$ is a vector space, $W \subseteq V$ is a subspace and $b \in V$ then $b + W$ is an affine subspace according to the definition you quote because it has a natural transitive free action of $W$ on $b + W$ given by

$$ w(b + w_1) = b + (w_1 + w) $$

(where we use the multiplicative notation for left group actions).

The set $H_{\alpha,1}$ has a natural transitive free action of $H_{\alpha}$ given by

$$ \lambda \cdot (\lambda') = \lambda + \lambda', \,\,\,\,\, \lambda \in H_{\alpha}, \lambda' \in H_{\alpha,1} $$

and thus has the structure of an affine subspace.

Comment: Now everything is clear to me. Thank you so much for your effort.